# Can't connect to Derby network server, Not clear what the issue is

Tags: tomcat, web-deployment, derby

I am able to connect fine using 'ij' but when I try to deploy my warfile, I can't seem to get a proper connection.   I am suspecting it has something to do with derbyclient.jar,  but I have that added to my classpath, so the JVM should not have any issues finding it.   I've spend a few days on this now, and I think it's time to ask on here.    PS: I am new to deploying on remote servers,  (it works fine on my local server).  The catalina.out log file is below.  What's really strange is that the webapp partially works.  It is able to pull some (but not all) needed data from the database even though it says its not connected.

```
Caused by: ERROR 08001: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 64,414 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetAgent.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.newAgent_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:271)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 74 more
```

I am using Tomcat 8.5, Derby 10.13 and running a Derby as a NetworkServer on the same remote computer as tomcat.   The error does not say much, so I really don't have a clear idea of what the problem is.  I am guessing that it can't find c derby jar files because it shows "(unknown Source" for some of them, (but that is just a guess).  I did read some other posts that talked about dropping derbyclient.jar into tomcats lib folder, but I am not even sure if that is what the problem is.

I used the following tutorial to install tomcat: [digitial Oceans tomcat installation guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04)  I am not really sure how the setup would work on a remote machine.  There is a lot of stuff about setting up permissions, and it isn't really explained why those permission are set.  Why not just install tomcat for my user?   What the point of creating a 'tomcat' user group?  It adds a lot of complexity to the problem without any clear explaination of why we are doing that and what the ramifications are.

Right now my current strategy is to follow the tutorial to the end, and then try the tools in the comments below to diagnose what the problem is exactly. 
Hopefully it wont take me another week to figure this out..

Comment: No, you've found derbyclient.jar just fine, otherwise you'd get a ClassNotFoundException, and you wouldn't have lines in your exception stack trace showing org.apache.derby.client.net.* classes. You might not be seeing the *entire* exception. To make sure that you are, do this: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: "Connection refused" could mean that your Derby Network Server isn't up and running on localhost:64414. Or, it could mean that the Derby Network Server is up and running, but some network firewall or other network configuration is preventing the connection. What operating system are you running on? Do you know enough about networking to perform some basic networking diagnostics? (e.g., the `netstat` comment, the `telnet` command, the `ping` command, etc.) If so, see if you can narrow down why your web app can't initiate a network connection to localhost:64414.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 15.10,  on GoDaddy,  I have heard of those tools before, but have never used them in practise,  I will give them a shot.

Comment: I am not sure what's going on now because I am no longer getting "refused to connect"  but I still can't connect.. netstat clearly says that localhost:64414 is listening.  When I try to run my webapp I get error code 500,   there is a null pointer exception in my database access object.  So there is certainly an issue connecting to the server.  But there are no clues so far as to why that is.

Comment: I THINK I FOUND IT,    on the client side I make ajax calls by using http://localhost:8080/context/ajaxRequest.do   But on the client side, localhost is the CLIENTS ip  not the SERVERS ip,  so that's why none of my requests are getting to the server.   (At least that's what I think the problem is) lets see how it pans out.

Comment: ITs turns out that was the issue, all along,    all my ajax requests on the client side javascript referred to localhost instead of the remote servers IP.   However, I am not sure why I got the connection refused message on the database.    Just happy I got it working right now.

Comment: You can put your own solution in as an answer, to tidy up this question and indicate how you figured out the solution. Others may find that useful in the future.

Comment: I will, it turns out there was multiple issues, I will do a better write up in a moment.  Thanks for your help Bryan.

Answer (score 1):

There were multiple mistakes:

**The First Problem**

In my javascript code where I was doing Ajax calls using JQuery, I forgot to change the domain from localhost to the host's domain.  i.e I was using $.get("http://localhost:8080/request.do) instead of $.get("http://remoteServerIPAddress:8080/request.do).

So when I launched the app on the remote server, any ajax call made explicitly did not work.

The reason it did not work is because **localhost** refers to whatever computer the code is currently executing on.

Since its javascript code running on the clients browser (rather than on the server)  all ajax calls which used **localhost** in them were trying to make server requests to the client computer rather than the remote computer, like they should have been.

The diagram below helps explain: [image: my mistake]

**The Second Problem**

Derby's **./startNetworkServer** command requires that you use **sudo** before it for a webapp to connect to the database.

When I didn't use  *sudo* there was nothing signifying that something was wrong.  It appeared as though the network was started successfully and listening on port 64414.

However, when The webapp was started I'd get "connection refused" with no clear explanations as to why.  Only through trial and error (and several hours) did I discover this was the cause.

On a personal note, I very much dislike 'sudo'.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the "sudo" part, sounds like maybe you might want to do some more investigation to understand what precisely was occurring there (could be network security, could be filesystem security, could be something else entirely), but anyway I'm glad you got your app working and thanks for the clear diagram and detailed description!

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I'll update my answer when I discover why I had to use sudo.